# How to check if the path exist in variable PATH using bash

Tags: bash

```
PATH=\one:\one\two:\one\two\three:
```

How to check the 'one\two' string using bash?

Comment: split the values of PATH with ":" as a delimiter, store the split parts in an array and then compare each array element against the path you want. Now could you try writing some basic code.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | grep '^\\one\\two$'
```

All that does is replace the `:` separator with a newline character, which allows `grep` to match each path exactly rather than including subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this,

```
echo ${PATH} | grep -e 'one\\two'
```

?

Note: This will also match paths of subdirectories within `one\two`

Comment: My favorite approach in such case - `echo ":$PATH:" | grep -e ':one\\two:'` :-)

Answer (score 0):

using `grep` will be easier, if your `grep` supports `-q`, you can suppress the output

```
grep -q 'one\\two' <<< "$PATH" && echo found || echo not found
```

otherwise

```
grep 'one\\two' <<< "$PATH" > /dev/null && echo found || echo not found
```